# How to use Javascript in PDF to format all the free text annotation (such as bold)?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a lot of PDF files with countless free text annotation. I try to use Javascript to batch modify the format of the annotation to make it bold and set the font to Times New Roman. I tried these code in PDF-XChange-editor.
I checked the API mentioned in PDF-XChange-editor (https://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/355-How-do-I-use-JavaScript-in-PDF-XChange-Editor)
And I refer the more detail API information in this (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf). Although the detail API info is for acrobat, the info works in PDF-XChange-editor also.

I tried the following method:

```
var annt = this.getAnnots(1)[0]
app.alert(annt.textFont)
annt.textFont = "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
var spans = new Array();

spans[0] = new Object();
spans[0].text = annt.contents;
spans[0].textColor = color.red;
spans[0].textSize = 24;
spans[0].alignment = "center";
spans[0].fontWeight = 800;  //set bold
spans[0].textFont = "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
annt.richContents = spans
```

This gave me the bold text, but the font changed to Arial and cannot set the font back to Times New Roman...

So, I tried another way...

```
var annt = this.getAnnots(1)[0]
var span = annt.richContents
span[0].fontWeight = 800  //set bold
annt.richContents = span
```

However, this does nothing...

Can anyone suggest good methods to do this? It is difficult to change the format one by one...
Thank a lot!

Comment: Can you include in your question a link to the pdf library you are using and version. If you are not using a library, can you explain how is it that you are able to change a pdf client-side? OK ... I see your change as requested on mention of PDF-XChange. Can you answer in comments on version?

Comment: I just run the javascript in the PDF-XChange-Editor. So, I think it is native support? The version is 8.0.336
I am using this API reference (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf)

Comment: Doubt its native support. If such app has that feature its likely to script the app itself. But then I don't really know what you mean by "native". Have you had a look at the app's API/Documentation?

Comment: I check the API reference and the Javascript is wrote and run in the PDF-XChange. I check the API here (https://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/355-How-do-I-use-JavaScript-in-PDF-XChange-Editor).

Comment: Well admitted without having looked at the API, since you want to change *all* "annots" shouldn't you be using a loop in your code? You write `this.getAnnots(1)[0]`. Don't you want them all to then loop thru instead? Check the docs on "getAnnots()".

Comment: Yes, I will do that if the first one can be modified as expected... However, in my attempts, it fails.

Comment: Makes sense, can you update your question with the link from *PDF-XChange-editor* that mentions it supports the javascript library you did post? Generally in-app scripting languages have their own API. And unless specifically mentioned it supports a third-party, it may not be solvable with the code you posted. Upvoted you. Its a good question. I've used that app before also. But never scripted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208537/discussion-between-getset-and-ps2pspgood).